# Laravel insert data run out of memory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4.2, I am using an Artisan command that reads data from a fixed length text files and inserts into our database.  I need to insert this data into our database using a connection that is not the default.  When I do this, I run out of memory while parsing the data. 'Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted'.  **Why do I run out of memory using the non-default database connection, but when I use the 'default' database
connection it works?**

If I use the 'default' connection, I can load the data with no errors.  Works perfect except the data is in the wrong database.

If I use the 'static' connection (connection that is not the default), I run out of memory every time.

**Thinks I've tried with no success:**

I am disabling query logging.

```
\DB::disableQueryLog();
```

Change the database default connection.

```
\Config::set('database.default', \Config::get('database.static'));
```

Use Model as Eloquent Model with DB insert

```
$model = new \vendor\VendorCat();
\DB::connection(\Config::get('database.static'))
   ->table('vendorcat')
   ->insert($model->toArray());
```

Use Model as stdClass

```
$model = new \stdClass();
\DB::connection(\Config::get('database.static'))
    ->table('vendorcat')
    ->insert(json_decode(json_encode($model), TRUE));
```

Database Config:

```
return array(
 'log' => FALSE,
 'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
 'default' => 'mysql',
 'static' => 'defaultstatic',
 'connections' => array(
 'mysql' => array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'database' => 'PRODUCTION',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
  'prefix' => '',
  ),
 'defaultstatic' => array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'database' => 'PRODUCTIONSTATIC',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
  'prefix' => '',
  ),
 ),
 'migrations' => 'migrations',
 'redis' => array(
  'cluster' => FALSE,
  'default' => array(
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => 6379,
  'database' => 0,
  ),
 ),
);
```

Code used to process data:

```
\DB::disableQueryLog();
$list = scandir($path, SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING);
foreach($list as &$file) {
  $fullpath = $path . '/' . $file;
  $pi = pathinfo($fullpath);
  if ( strcasecmp('dat', $pi['extension']) != 0 ) {
    continue;
  }
  $cnt++;
  $this->processFile($fullpath);
  $fullpath = null;
  unset($fullpath);
  $pi = null;
  unset($pi);
}
$list = null;
unset($list);



while ( ! feof($hdl) ) {
  $line = fread($hdl, $len);  // fixed length text 1503 bytes
  if ($line === FALSE) break;
  if (strlen($line) == 0) break;
  $model = new \vendor\VendorCat();
  //$model = new stdClass();
  /** set model properties, 86 properties, example... */
  $model->engprop = trim(substr($line, 1174, 1));
  $model->engho = trim(substr($line, 1176, 1));

  $model->save();

  // $model->setConnection(\Config::get('database.static'))->save();

  // $model = new \vendor\VendorCat();
  // \DB::connection(\Config::get('database.static'))
  //   ->table('vendorcat')
  //   ->insert($model->toArray());

  // $model = new \stdClass();
  // \DB::connection(\Config::get('database.static'))
  //   ->table('vendorcat')
  //   ->insert(json_decode(json_encode($model), TRUE));

  $line = null;
  unset($line);
  $model = null;
  unset($model);
}
```

Comment: Do you have xdebug on?

Comment: Xdebug is not on, plus I only get the error when not using the default connection.  If I use the default connection, I do not get a memory error.

Comment: Maybe this is an memory leak: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1641

Comment: @daniel-o , DB::disablyequerylog only applies to the default connection, so that is my problem.  I have to disable it for each connection.  If you want to provide an answer that disablequerylog needs to be disabled on the alternate connection, you can receive all the glory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB::disableQueryLog() only applies to the default connection. So you have to disable it for each connection (to prevent the memory leak).

Answer (score -3):

I've not read the whole problem. but the error message can be solved this way:change memory_limit in php.ini configuration file . It might work after this.

Comment: My memory limit is 1GB and i'm processing 1500 byte lines at a time, there is a different problem.  Thanks.